# Determine whether user profile belongs to current user in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In my application, I have the concept of a user profile. The information that gets displayed differs depending on whether the user is viewing their own profile or another user's profile. Here's a simplified view of `UsersController@show`:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $currentUser = Auth::user();
    return view ('users.show', compact('user', 'currentUser'));
}
```

In my view, I end up having to write code that looks like:

```
@if ($currentUser === $user->id)
 <section class="container search-form visible-nav">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            @include ('partials._search')
        </div>
    </div>
 </section>
@endif
```

This seems like a clumsy implementation, especially for a language like Laravel. Is there a more concise way to achieve the same result in my views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. You need to check if current user is the viewed user somewhere - either in the controller or in the view.

You could simplify your code a bit though:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    return view ('users.show', compact('user'));
}

@if (Auth::id() === $user->id)
<section class="container search-form visible-nav">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            @include ('partials._search')
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
@endif
```

There are some other options like returning different blade templates depending on whether the current user is the same as the viewed user, but if the only difference would be a few @ifs I would keep it in one template.

Comment: Thanks for the code clean-up tip! Yes, ultimately, will want to explore different views, but the layout is simple enough currently that it's not worth the effort.